# How do I top align two tables of different sizes to be side by side using knitr::kable()

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I'm attempting to place two tables next to one another for comparison sake. The issue I'm having is that when I knit in rmarkdown the second table (less rows) is placed in the middle of the first table, or vice versa depending on how many rows are in each. I want them to both be top aligned. I've valign, hold_position, and HOLD_position to no avail.

Below is a fully reproducible example of the issue using rmarkdown and mtcars

{r mtcars, echo = F, fig.pos = "H"}

```
cars1 <- 
  mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "car") %>% 
  select(car:disp) %>% 
  head(8)

cars2 <- 
  mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "car") %>% 
  select(car:disp) %>% 
  tail(4)


knitr::kable(
  list(
    cars1,
    cars2
  ),
valign = 't'
) %>% 
  kableExtra::kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed"),
                            latex_options = "hold_position")
```

[mtcars table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7x3f9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Sincerily I don't know how to solve this using **knitr** options and parameters.

But I suggest you a contour solution using **flexdashboards** where you may create two (or more) columns and plot each table in its own column, resulting in the figure below with the tables side by side and top aligned. But I don't know if your markdown purposes admits the use of flexdashboards.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kirk. Unfortunately I'm trying to do this using xaringan slides to embed the tables side by side in a slide show :(

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is to use latex to manually adjust the height of the shorter graph such that it is aligned with the taller graph.

First make `kable` tables for each table, respectively:

```
cars1 <- 
  mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "car") %>% 
  select(car:disp) %>% 
  head(8) %>% 
  kbl(booktabs = T)

cars2 <- 
  mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "car") %>% 
  select(car:disp) %>% 
  tail(4) %>% 
  kbl(booktabs = T)
```

Then use latex code to align the tables side by side:

```
cat(c("\\begin{table}[!htb]
    \\begin{minipage}{.5\\linewidth}
    \\caption{The first table}",
        cars1,
    "\\end{minipage}%
    \\begin{minipage}{.5\\linewidth}
    \\caption{The second table}
    \\vspace*{-19mm}",
        cars2,
    "\\end{minipage} 
\\end{table}"
))
```

The key line here is `\\vspace*{-19mm}`, which manually adjusts the second table height. Here is the result:
[image]

Comment: When I paste the latex code into a rmd chunk it just returns the latex. I'll just paste the first few lines. Is there something else that I'm missing?

\begin{table}[!htb]
##     \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
##     \caption{The first table} <table>

Comment: Thanks for the question. You may need to add results='asis' in your chunk header to get the results. 

Like so: `{r sample, results='asis'}`